# multi-page scan to PDF using HP all-in-one on a Linux machine

Tags: linux, drivers, scanner, hp-officejet, proprietary

Switched Mom and Dad's computer to Linux some time back. All has gone well save a couple little things. One of these is the HP all-in-one printer (Officejet 6700). On Windows, Dad used to be able to quickly scan a multi-page document to PDF using the feeder tray. On Linux, with the cruder, more generic scan driver, he can do scans one at a time on the glass, but the driver (probably) is not aware of the all-in-one device's advanced features such as the auto feeder.

Is there a way around this? More sophisticated drivers, or some clever scripting solution?

Comment: do you use the [official HP linux driver](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/models/officejet/officejet_6700) or some other driver?

Comment: @NordlysJeger Thanks. Unfortunately HPLIP doesn't work for me. And with what documentation I could find the first go-round I wasn't really sure if it would do what I needed anyways. I've come back to it since and it seems like I should be using it.... but no luck getting it to run. I get python tracebacks about a missing module when i try to run any of the HPLIP tools.